# C#: What is the best method to send support request via email?

Tags: c#, email

I have a windows forms application that I am adding a request support form to, and would like the user to be able to input the values and hit a button. Once the button is pushed I can either:

1. Open a new mail message and auto populate the message. (Not sure how to do this)
2. Submit the request via a http form on my website. (I know how to do this)
3. Send an email directly from the code of the application. (I know how to do this)

What I want to know is what would be the best method to use? I think option 1 is the most transparent, and the user will see exactly what is being sent, but I am not sure how to ensure it works no matter what email client they use.

I see there being potential issues with option two, specifically a firewall possibly stopping the submission. But option 2 would allow me to supply them with a ticket number right then and there for their request.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you can send mail using the System.Net.Mail objects, see http://www.systemnetmail.com for more information.  Not sure what to recommend on the options.

Comment: @Brian: I think that is option 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Option 1, as suggested, use the mailto handler.

Format your string like so: `string.Format("mailto:support@example.com?subject={0}&body={1}", subject, body)`. Don't forget to UrlEncode the subject and body values.

Then use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() with your string.

This will launch the registered mail handler (Outlook, Windows Live Mail, Thunderbird, etc) on the system.

Answer (score 1):

For option 1 : If the message body is short, then invoking the [mailto](http://www.ianr.unl.edu/internet/mailto.html) handler from inside your code no longer requires that they be using outlook.  It's kinda a cheap hack, but it's completely cross-platform for local mail clients.  (If they're using something like gmail, you're still SOL, though)

Answer (score 0):

Option 2) is the best to avoid enterprise firewall issues because the HTTP port may not be blocked.

Option 2) is the best for simple configuration. The only config key you will have is the service/page url. Then your SMTP configuration will stay on your webserver.

Now you will have to choose between using a webpage (if one already exists) or a webservice (which is best fitted for your feature).

Answer (score 0):

For option (1) be prepared to deal with Outlook version problems. But this is not hard (again if we are talking about Outlook, last version)

```
        //using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;       
        private void OutlookMail(string Subject, string Body)
        {

        ApplicationClass app = new ApplicationClass();
        NameSpaceClass ns = (NameSpaceClass)app.GetNamespace("mapi");
        ns.Logon("", "", true, true);
        MailItem mi =
            (MailItem)app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
        mi.Subject = Subject;

        int EOFPos = Body.IndexOf(char.Parse("\0"));
        if (EOFPos != -1)
        {
            log.Error("EOF found in Mail body");
            ErrorDialog ed = new ErrorDialog(TietoEnator.Common.ErrorDialog.ErrorDialog.Style.OK, "Export Error", "File could not be exported correctly, please inform responsible person", "", "EOF char detected in the body of email message.");
            ed.ShowDialog();
        Body=Body.Replace("\0", "");
        }
        mi.HTMLBody = "<html><head><META content='text/html; charset=CP1257' http-equiv=Content-Type></head><body><table>"+Body+"</table></body></html>";

        mi.BodyFormat = OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;//.olFormatPlain; 
        mi.Display(0); // show it non - modally
        ns.Logoff();
    }
```

---

BTW for automatic support requests I plan to use in my current project "Microsoft Enterprise Logging Support Block" email sending functionality.